# Android Studio - The device already has a newer version of this application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

FYI: I am using a simulator, because I do not own a Android Device (I have Play Store supported device on simulator).

So I have the original app from Play Store on my device, and in Android Studio, when running my application, I get the following message:

```
The device already has a newer version of this application.

In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application 

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data! 
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
    
[OK] [Cancel]
```

If I download the app from Play Store, and long press and select App Info, it says `Version 2.0.0`.

If I run the app from Android Studio, and long press and select App Info, it says `Version 3.0.0`.

**So**: The device has app version 2.0.0, I try to run version 3.0.0 from Android Studio, and get that message. How come?

This is in my build.gradle, not sure if that is needed for you guys to know, but:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.xxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyy.droid"
    minSdk = 33
    targetSdk = 33
    versionCode = 32
    versionName = "3.0.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Version name is just string displayed for the end user. Version code (an integer) is compared to determine if upgrade is happening.

Comment: @Pawel So in this case, what do I have to do?

Comment: Increment version code by 1 whenever you want your new version to be considered an upgrade. Do keep in mind you also need to use same signing key that was used for version published in the store.

Comment: @Pawel Ok, so I tried setting the versionCode higher, and now I get this message: `The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.`.

Comment: As I said they have to be signed with the exact same signing key (have the same signature) or they will be considered different apps. So you cannot push a debug version on top of your release apk. If you want to develop and keep the published version installed on the same device I suggest adding ".dev" package name suffix to your debug builds. If you want to do a "release" upgrade straight from studio you have to change your signing config to use same "app signing key" (NOT upload key) that's being used by play console signing.

Comment: @Pawel Where do I check the signing key? I had to make a new project, because my original project got deleted. I do have the `Keystore Alias` from the original project.

Comment: Use your original keystore file, there is no other way. If you've lost it (or never uploaded one and let console generate one) you should still be able to deploy updates through play console as it signs generated apks on their end but you have no way to to sign your app locally (at least not in a way that will make it an upgrade over the version on the store).

Comment: How do I use the keystore file when running from Android Studio on a simulator? Isn't that used when uploading the apk?

Answer (score 0):

When you update your application, you need to change the `versionCode` to +1.

The number in the `versionCode` determines whether one version is newer than another, with higher numbers indicating newer versions.

The `versionName` parameter is intended only to display the version of the app for users.

In addition, the `applicationId` must be the same as in the old version of the app (it is better not to change it at all).

More detailed information can be found in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning